# OSGi real advantage

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I'm experimenting with OSGi to build a modular IoT unit. It seems like the perfect technology if one would like to update parts of the system ( e.g. sensor code ) without sacrificing communication code and vice-versa.

The question is though :

> Why do I need to restart all dependent bundles when updating a service (inside a bundle )?

```
private void updateBundle(String f) {
    BundleContext mainBc = felix.getBundleContext();
    Bundle bundle = mainBc.getBundle(f);
    try {
        bundle.update();
    // if I don't do this, the services inside 'bundle' will NOT be updated
        PackageAdmin pa = mainBc.getService(mainBc.getServiceReference(PackageAdmin.class));
        pa.refreshPackages(mainBc.getBundles());
    // at this point all bundles were restarted
    } catch (BundleException e) {
        System.err.println("Error while updating  " + f);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Judging by the fact that all my bundles were restarted ( or at least dependent ones ), what is the point of updating the class definitions in a  bundle since all app bundles will be `stopped` and `started` resetting all state and active connections ?

It's exactly like restarting my app from the command line, so why would I need osgi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem the package holding the service interface class is exported by your service implementation bundle. So when the service implementation bundle is updated, so is the exported package. Thus all bundles consuming the service are using the old revision of the exported package unlike your service implementation bundle. Thus, you must refresh all those service consuming bundles to make sure they use the same revision of the exported package as your service implementation bundle.

This is why you want to export the package containing the service interface class from a different bundle than the service implementation bundle. Then all service consuming bundles *and* the service implementation bundle import the package from the exporting bundle. Then when you update the service implementation bundle, you do not need to refresh the service consuming bundles.

So, generally, you do not want a bundle which may be updated frequently to be exporting packages which must be imported by other bundles that care about the function of the updating bundle, such as a service.

Comment: Sounds fair. And I would need to create 2 bundles for each 'module' (conceptually speaking) of my app. 1 bundle to hold the service interface class and 1 bundle containing the service implementation class. This way, when I update the implementation I would need only to restart those two... Ok I will give it a try.

Comment: Ok, seems to work ok in this regard. One more question though. If I want to update a module I call `bundle.update()` this triggers restart, but in order to refreshe dependent packages I run `packageAdmin.refreshPackages()` which also causes a restart. Is there a work-around to not trigger restart twice  ?

Comment: Well you can stop the bundle, update the bundle, refresh the packages and then restart the bundle. But if you separate your implementation into its own bundle, it likely does not even exports any package and so calling refresh packages on it is pointless. You only need to do refresh packages when an exporting bundle is updated and you want the importing bundles to be refreshed.

Comment: Right you are. Any idea on how i can test whether a bundle is exporting packages just by having a reference to the bundle ? This in order to refresh packages only when needed

Comment: bundle.adapt(BundleWiring.class) will return the BundleWiring object for a bundle and you can then ask the BundleWiring about exported packages.